# How to start multiple Machinery workers?

Tags: go, redis, queue, task

I am new to golang Machinery, the following is the code on the doc to start workers [machinery workers](https://github.com/RichardKnop/machinery#workers)

```
worker := server.NewWorker("worker_name", 10)
err := worker.Launch()
if err != nil {
  // do something with the error
}
```

My first question is, does `server.NewWorker("worker_name", 10)` start 10 workers? or it means something else, if not, how do I start 10 workers if needed, run `go run example/machinery.go worker` 10 times?

My second question is related to the first parameter consumerTag, where can I find the place tags are used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this line:

```golang
worker := server.NewWorker("worker_name", 10)
```

Starts a new worker. You need to run multiple instances to start new workers. 10 is the number of concurrent goroutines that specific worker is going to be running. If you have 10 tasks in the queue they can run concurrently.

For the tag, you need to check the specific implementation for each broker in the codebase.

Comment: What is the difference between running 10 worker instances (using NewWorker to launch each) or running just one worker instance with 10 goroutines?